# High Charts add variance instead of values

Tags: highcharts, dotnethighcharts

Hi am using high charts in my website and they are just awesome.I wold like to know whether there is any option to include variance in graph instead of the original values like the one in below snip[image].

instead of displaying the values of each bars i would like to display the difference between two.Is this possible?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enabled dataLabels for one series, and disable for second one. Then in [dataLabels.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter) you need to compare values, and return value you want.

Comment: Thanks for replying.Do you have any sample ?

Comment: added it to my asp.net webpage everything else works except the formatter.It throws this error TypeError: this.series.chart.series[0].data[x] is undefined .Can you help me fix this out

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LqJaB/ here is the link to the fiddle i created .You can see the same error over here.

Comment: Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/LqJaB/3/ The problem was with categories where `this.x` is category name, not category index. To get category index we need to use `this.point.x`

Comment: awesome this works..Any way to add color to those value like red if negative and green if positive.Is that doable?

Comment: Before returning value check if is positive or negative. Then return simple <span> tag with inline CSS for colors.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again .Is there a way i can bring the variance to the second bar.I tried this http://jsfiddle.net/karthi89msc/3bQne/305/ but second and first values looks same

Comment: It's little tricky but possible - use `options.data[x]` because second series isn't rendered while first is going to render labels. Also, make sure you are using second series, not the first one still.. (`series[1]` should be there) otherwise you are removing from first series the same series' value. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/308/